# php whatsapp link with variable

Tags: php, sql, api, admin, whatsapp

I would like to do the following in my webpage:

1. users submit a form then write the date into phpmyadmin. It is ok for
   me.
2. then the webpage automatically open whatsapp and start the
   conversation in whatsapp with some text.

Now I can start the whatapp conversation but no text！ Please help.

here with my code:

```
                            $txt = " happy ";
                            $link = "<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=1;url='https://wa.me/85265648596?text=$txt'>";

                                    $sql = "insert into Enrol (`Name`, `Tel`, `Year`, `Enquiry`) values ('$Name', '$Tel', '$Year', '$Enquiry')";


                                            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
                                            {

                                                echo $txt;

                                                echo $link;


                                            }
```

Comment: you are using the code in very wrong way. u shud nvr give users access to phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how it already works, if your text does *not* contain a space at the beginning …?

You need to properly URL-encode the value, if it contains “special” characters.

```
$link = "<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=1;url='https://wa.me/85265648596?text=" .
           urlencode($txt) . "'>";
```